# finding marginal probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

The random variable X has a range of {0,1,2} and a random variable Y has a range of {1,2}. The joint distribution of X and Y is given by following table-

```
 x     y     P(X=x,Y=y)
--------------------
 0     1        0.2
 0     2        0.1
 1     1        0.0
 1     2        0.2
 2     1        0.3
 2     2        0.2
```

a)Write down table for marginal distribution of X and Y, i.e. give the values of P(X=x) for all x and P(Y=y) for all y.

According to me -

```
 x     P(X=x)             y    P(Y=y)
 ----------                ----------

 0      1/3               1     1/2
 1      1/3               2     1/2
 2      1/3
```

Is this correct solution or not ?

Comment: Which *method* did you use? Unless you say that...

Answer (score 1):

No... and yes.

Although the second table is correct, the first is way off.

Further, from your presentation, I suspect the second table is only *accidentally* correct, and not derived by the proper procedure.   There is a reason examiners mark the ability to *show your work* and not just the final answer.

You need to obtain the probability values for the magins by using the Law of Total Probability.   Just counting the outcomes is incorrect as they are explicitly not equally probable; you must properly weigh them, and you *are given* their probability mass.

For example: $\mathsf P(X{=}0) ~=~ \mathsf P(X{=}0, Y{=}1)+\mathsf P(X{=}0, Y{=}2) ~=~ 0.3$ and so on.